# Is there a setting in a Linux file manager to show copy progress the way Finder in macOS does?

Tags: linux, macintosh, file-manager, finder

I was looking for a convenient file manager to move a lot of files and folders on Linux and needed to see as much detail as possible. Unfortunately I had some problems too, with some errors (details at the end of [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1615545/1039759)) and had to restart the copy process a few times while having difficulties in identifying which files and folders have already been copied and which have not.

As I had a Mac on hand, I tried that too and very conveniently was able to see within the output window in Finder which files or folders were already copied (normal font), which were in the list to be copied (grayed font), and, among these, which were in the process of being copied (progress bar).

[image]

Is there a file manager for Linux with similar features? I mean at least one of the two (a progress bar for each item under processing and a list of what is in the waiting list).

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov - I see no such option. Even if you didn't try it, maybe you know where that is?